# 25.12 LAB: Matching strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Write a program that compares two strings given as input. Output the number of characters that match in each string position. The output should use the correct verb (match vs matches) according to the character count.

I try to break out of the first loop if the first characters don't match, but that just causes the outer loop to keep iterating without going back into the second.

```
statment1 = input()
statment2 = input()
x =0
for char in statment1:
    for letter in statment2:
        if char == letter:
            x+=1
        else:
            break
```

Comment: give some input and expected output

Comment: You don't need the `else: break` statement. Since it's asking for position wise: you should just do `for i, j in zip(statement1, statement2)`

Answer (score 0):

This code solution may find you useful

```
def compare_strings(string1, string2):
    length = min(len(string1), len(string2))
    count = 0
    for i in range(length):
        if string1[i] == string2[i]:
            count += 1
    
    if count == 0:
        print("No characters match.")
    elif count == 1:
        print("1 character matches.")
    else:
        print(f"{count} characters match.")

# Example usage:
string1 = input("Enter the first string: ")
string2 = input("Enter the second string: ")

compare_strings(string1, string2)
```